# Is there a way to install IE 11 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, installation, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 supports only Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 and some others yes, but not Windows 8.0. So is there are way to make it work by changing some files or something?

I can not upgrade to 8.1 since it's my office computer which takes the licenses directly through network and right now we don't have any 8.1 license.

Comment: No.  Why don't you just upgrade to Windows 8.1?  IE11 is only supported on Windows 7 and comes already installed on Windows 8.1 no other versions of Windows are supported.

Comment: edited question, I can't upp to 8.1

Comment: A Windows 8.0 license has the ability to activate Windows 8.1 it just cannot be used to install Windows 8.1.  If you are running Windows 8.0 Enterprise you can simply use a generic Windows 8.1 Enterprise key.  In other words until you upgrade to Windows 8.1 you will be unable to install IE 11.

Comment: Has Microsoft actually detailed why Windows 8.0 users cannot install IE11? or is it just to push everyone to Windows 8.1.

Comment: I think it's to push to 8.1 but not sure. To me it makes no sense.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me - Either you have retail copies and can upgrade to 8.1, or you have a volume licenses edition and should be able to acquire 8.1 keys from the volume license centre.... If your admin doesn't want you to upgrade, then I can understand that. However, if you are allowed to install IE 11/the point of this question, I guess you are allowed to do stuff on your local computer, so, take a look at this blog post I wrote: http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2014/03/how-to-upgrade-windows-8-volume-license.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an office computer that the user should be speaking with their company IT about.

Answer (score -1):

Register to download the Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry 180 day Evaluation and get the product key:
http://microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/download-8-1-industry.aspx

Comment: thank you, unfortunately this is not an option. My software is managed by our system and we are not allowed to upgrade.